# Python removing quotes

Tags: python, string

Hi I am trying to strip quotes from a string. 
This is how I get the string

```
lists=['"4"','"2"','"3"','"1"']

des=" ".join(lists)

print (des)
```

I get "4" "3" "2" "1"

I than try

```
des.replace('"', '')
print(des)
```

And I still get the same result, quotes still in the string.
Does anyone know why this is happening. Does it have to do with the .join statement?

Comment: `des = des.replace(...)`

Comment: Oh ok thanks I guess I misunderstood the replace method. Thanks!

Comment: `''.join(d.replace('"', '') for d in lists)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) doesn't modify the string *in place*. This means that in order for anything to happen, you need to assign the result to a variable.

For example:

```
string1 = "foo"
string2 = string1.replace("foo", "bar")

print(string1)
>>> "foo"

print(string2)
>>> "bar"
```

`string1` stays the same, and `string2` has the modified value.

So in your case you want:

```
des = des.replace('"', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lists=['"4"','"2"','"3"','"1"']
des=" ".join(value.strip('"') for value in lists)
```

#### Output

```
'4 2 3 1'
```

Comment: You can improve the speed of your code by using a list comprehension rather than a generator comprehension: `" ".join([value.strip('"') for value in lists])`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like below:

```
lists=['"4"','"2"','"3"','"1"']    
des=" ".join(lists)        
des = des.replace('"', '')    
print (des)
```

As des doesn't have any idea if the values are replaced or not. You have to reassign, then you will get the following output:

```
4 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a variable or `des` itself to save the replaced string.

```
des=des.replace('"', '')
```